# How to consider word pairs/phrases for Word2Vec and other pre-processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

So it's my first time using Word2Vec and Im using a wikipedia dump with WikiCorpus to pre-process the file before training my Word2Vec model. I want to use the following pre-processing techniques:

1. Convert all letters to lowercase (I think WikiCorpus does this already).
2. Remove all punctuation (Done by WikiCorpus).
3. Consider word pairs/phrases as a single word, for example 'Big Apple' -> 'big_apple', not 'big', 'apple'.
4. Convert all digits to their word forms, so '3' -> 'three'

At the moment I have no idea how to do the last two. I know about num2text but not sure how to incorporate with WikiCorpus or Word2vec. Can anyone help?

Comment: 3. Are you looking for [collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)? 
4. `my_string.replace('3', 'three')`?

Comment: Have you looked at gensim? https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/ You not only can train your wordvectors but have also a lot of preprocessing tools like bigrams and trigrams.

Comment: Yes have looked at gensim, but am confused about what stage to do the preprocessing. I know that saying corpus = WikiCorpus(‘.xml.bz2 file, lemmatize=false) does some for me (lower casing, punctuation removal) and then would I use other gensim packages before the whole model = Word2Vec(corpus,.......)? Is there a way to incorporate it with the WikiCorpus class to lessen the time it takes?